# NextAuth Server Page redirects to the home page

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I use NextAuth within a Next.js 13.4 version. I use getServerSession() to read the session in a server page. If a user is not logged in and clicks on a button that calls up a server page, he must first be logged in. The The problem is that the user is not redirected to the NewPage after successful registration, but to the home page

app/new/page.tsx:

```
export default async function NewProduct() {
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

if (!session) {
 //User is directed to Home after successful login
 redirect("/auth/signIn?callbackUrl=/protected/server");
}
return (
 ...
)
```